# Does measure theory provide some notion of "conservation of mass"?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am learning measure theory in the context of probability. We cannot, in general allow the power set of $\Omega$ (which I denote $\textrm{powset}(\Omega)$) to be the domain of our probability measure, and must instead restrict it to a well behaved $\mathcal{F} \subset \textrm{powset}(\Omega)$.

To play with what I understand about "Vitali sets", I am wondering about the following: take for example the interval $[0, 1)$ as $\Omega$.

(1) A problem with it is that it in some sense contains many copies of itself: take some $x, y \in [0, 1)$ such that $x < y$, then there is a bijection between $[x, y)$ and $[0, 1)$ given by $f(x) = x/y$, so they have the same cardinality, and if we were defining a measure based on cardinality, then we would run into various problems.

Andreas writes:

> it would be very boring if all sets of the same cardinality had equal measure. An example for a measure is the Lebesgue measure which just measures the length of an interval. In this case: $P([x,y))=y−x$ and $P([0,1))=1$.

But suppose one consider shifts (translations) of $[x, y)$ within $[0, 1)$. It would be nice if each of these had $P([x + k, y + k)) = P([x, k))$, but this causes $P([0, 1)) = \infty$, which is problematic as we would also like it to be $1$.

(2) How valid is the intuition that the problem with (1) is that there is no way to talk about something like "conservation of mass"? There are too many copies of the same thing within itself, so there is "infinite mass"?

(3) If (2) is on the right track, where is "conservation of mass" hidden inside the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: It seems like you are confusing two different notions of "size" or "mass": It is true that $[x, y)$ and $[0, 1)$ have the same *cardinality* as sets because there exists a bijection between them. However, that does not imply that these two sets should have equal *measure* - after all, it would be very boring if all sets of the same cardinality had equal measure. An example for a measure is the Lebesgue measure which just measures the length of an interval. In this case: $P([x, y))=y-x$ and $P([0, 1))=1$.

Comment: No, the issue with Vitali sets has nothing to do with wanting bijections of sets to preserve measure.  The property of Lebesgue measure $m$ that Vitali sets take advantage of is translation invariance: the idea that we want $m([a,b)) = m([a+x,b+x))$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  It is only these specific bijections (i.e. shifting) that we want to preserve measure.  This is a concept that is generally not carried over to probability measures, as there is no reason in general that the probability of a random variable lying in a set should be invariant to shifts.

Comment: @user6247850 Thanks! Your comment, together with what Andreas said, helps me understand why we are more concerned with shifts (what I see in textbooks). I suppose I can also clarify my question now: I think do not quite understand why sigma-algebras make the problem posed by the shift-construction go away.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you! I fixed my original post now to consider the shifts of `[x, y)` rather than `[x, y)` itself.

Comment: @bzm3r Why do you think that translation invariance implies $P([0, 1)) = \infty$? Also note that translation invariance is not some general property of measures. Some measures have this property (e.g. the Lebesgue measure, because its purpose is to measure length and it should not change under shifts) but many other measures do not have this property (e.g. any probability distribution other than the uniform one).